# Can I display the number of iterations and each iteration result when using fmin_tnc?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I've been tasked with using fmin_tnc for an optimization problem. For the time being, I am only allowed to use fmin_tnc. I would like to display the number of iterations whether or not the results converge. Upon convergence (or line search error, which I often get), I receive a string of numbers, but they are not labeled so I'm not sure if one of them is an iteration number or function evaluation.

Additionally, I would like to store the values of my function output every time fmin_tnc iterates it.

So far, I can only find answers revolving around "fmin" but not "fmin_tnc". The code for the optimizer is as follows (unfortunately, I am not allowed to show more than this):

```
optimize.fmin_tnc(func1, x0, approx_grad=True, bounds=(bounds), epsilon=0.001, messages=15, stepmx=21, ftol=1e-06, xtol=1e-6)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation of the `fmin_tnc` function? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc.html. There is  a `callback` keyword argument, which probably fits your needs.

Comment: I have, and I guess I thought I would get something more along the lines of 'retall' instead like the other optimizers. I don't understand at all what callback(xk) means, or what the parameter vector would be/how it would be put into this "xk" format.

Comment: `callback` is a function you can define. As the docs state, this function gets called after each iteration. Its input is the current parameter vector after the iteration is done. You can e.g. `print(vk)` in your callback to see the parameter vector after each iteration step.